# How to share shiro session in distributed system?

Tags: java, shiro

I have two distributed web apps A and B(A is the same as B), i am using shiro to share the http sessions between two apps. But I don't know how to implement it,I want some help.
Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: I think you can use redis or other distributed cache to store shiro's session.

Answer (score 1):

Shiro has official modules for [Hazelcast](https://stormpath.com/blog/hazelcast-support-apache-shiro) and EhCache.
The above Hazelcast links to a blog post with an example of two applications sharing sessions.

Answer (score -1):

I hope [shiro-redis](https://github.com/alexxiyang/shiro-redis) can give you some help. Maybe this code is not recently. But you can study his method. Then you can create your code.

I will give you some code as follows:

1 sessionDao

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

import org.apache.shiro.session.Session;
import org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.SimpleSession;
import org.apache.shiro.session.mgt.eis.EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO;

public class SessionRedisDao extends EnterpriseCacheSessionDAO {

    // create session , store to db
    @Override
    protected Serializable doCreate(Session session) {
        Serializable sessionId = super.doCreate(session);
        RedisDb.setObject(sessionId.toString().getBytes(), sessionToByte(session));

        return sessionId;
    }

    // get session
    @Override
    protected Session doReadSession(Serializable sessionId) {
        // firstly get session from cache，if null then get it from db
        Session session = super.doReadSession(sessionId); 
        if(session == null){
            byte[] bytes = RedisDb.getObject(sessionId.toString().getBytes());
            if(bytes != null && bytes.length > 0){
                session = byteToSession(bytes);    
            }
        }
        return session;
    }


    @Override
    protected void doUpdate(Session session) {
        super.doUpdate(session);
        RedisDb.setObject(session.getId().toString().getBytes(), sessionToByte(session));
    }

    // delete session
    @Override
    protected void doDelete(Session session) {
        super.doDelete(session);
        RedisDb.delString(session.getId() + "");
    }

    // convert session object to byte, then store it to redis
    public byte[] sessionToByte(Session session){
        ByteArrayOutputStream bo = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] bytes = null;
        try {
            ObjectOutputStream oo = new ObjectOutputStream(bo);
            oo.writeObject(session);
            bytes = bo.toByteArray();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bytes;
    }

    // restore session
    public Session byteToSession(byte[] bytes){
        ByteArrayInputStream bi = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
        ObjectInputStream in;
        SimpleSession session = null;
        try {
            in = new ObjectInputStream(bi);
            session = (SimpleSession) in.readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return session;
    }

}
```

2. redis operator

   ```
   import java.util.Arrays;
   import java.util.Date;
   import java.util.Set;
   import redis.clients.jedis.Jedis;
   import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPool;
   import redis.clients.jedis.JedisPoolConfig;

   public class RedisDb {
   private static JedisPool jedisPool;
   // session expire time
   private static int expireTime = 1800;
   private static int countExpireTime = 2*24*3600;
   private static String password = "123456";
   private static String redisIp = "10.10.31.149";
   private static int redisPort = 6379;
   private static int maxActive = 200;
   private static int maxIdle = 200;
   private static long maxWait = 5000;
   private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RedisDb.class);

   static {
       initPool();
   }
   // init connect pool
   public static void initPool(){
       JedisPoolConfig config = new JedisPoolConfig();
       config.setMaxTotal(maxActive);
       config.setMaxIdle(maxIdle);
       config.setMaxWaitMillis(maxWait);
       config.setTestOnBorrow(false);
       jedisPool = new JedisPool(config, redisIp, redisPort, 10000, password);
   }
   // get connect from pool
   public static Jedis getJedis(){
       Jedis jedis = null;
       try{
           jedis = jedisPool.getResource();
           //            jedis.auth(password);
       } catch(Exception e){
           ExceptionCapture.logError(e);
       }

       return jedis;
   }
   // recycle connection
   public static void recycleJedis(Jedis jedis){
       if(jedis != null){
           try{
               jedis.close();
           } catch(Exception e){
               ExceptionCapture.logError(e);
           }
       }
   }
   // save string
   public static void setString(String key, String value){
       Jedis jedis = getJedis();
       if(jedis != null){
           try{
               jedis.set(key, value);
           } catch(Exception e){
               ExceptionCapture.logError(e);
           } finally{
               recycleJedis(jedis);
           }
       }

   }
   // get string data
   public static String getString(String key){
       Jedis jedis = getJedis();
       String result = "";
       if(jedis != null){
           try{
               result = jedis.get(key);
           }catch(Exception e){
               ExceptionCapture.logError(e);
           } finally{
               recycleJedis(jedis);
           }
       }

       return result;
   }
   // delete string 
   public static void delString(String key){
       Jedis jedis = getJedis();
       if(jedis != null){
           try{
               jedis.del(key);
           }catch(Exception e){
               ExceptionCapture.logError(e);
           } finally{
               recycleJedis(jedis);
           }
       }
   }
   // save byte data
   public static void setObject(byte[] key, byte[] value){
       Jedis jedis = getJedis();
       String result = "";
       if(jedis != null){
           try{
               if(!jedis.exists(key)){
                   jedis.set(key, value);
               }
               // redis中session过期时间
               jedis.expire(key, expireTime);
           } catch(Exception e){
               ExceptionCapture.logError(e);
           } finally{
               recycleJedis(jedis);
           }
       }
   }
   // get byte data 
   public static byte[] getObject(byte[] key){
       Jedis jedis = getJedis();
       byte[] bytes = null;
       if(jedis != null){
           try{
               bytes = jedis.get(key);;
           }catch(Exception e){
               ExceptionCapture.logError(e);
           } finally{
               recycleJedis(jedis);
           }
       }
       return bytes;

   }

   // update byte data 
   public static void updateObject(byte[] key){
       Jedis jedis = getJedis();
       if(jedis != null){
           try{
               // redis中session过期时间
               jedis.expire(key, expireTime);
           }catch(Exception e){
               ExceptionCapture.logError(e);
           } finally{
               recycleJedis(jedis);
           }
       }

   }

   // key value add 1
   public static void inc(String key){
       Jedis jedis = getJedis();
       if(jedis != null){
           try{
               if(!jedis.exists(key)){
                   jedis.set(key, "1");
                   jedis.expire(key, countExpireTime);
               } else {
                   // 加1
                   jedis.incr(key);
               }
           }catch(Exception e){
               ExceptionCapture.logError(e);
           } finally{
               recycleJedis(jedis);
           }
       }
   }

   // get all keys
   public static Set<String> getAllKeys(String pattern){
       Jedis jedis = getJedis();
       if(jedis != null){
           try{
               return jedis.keys(pattern);
           }catch(Exception e){
               ExceptionCapture.logError(e);
           } finally{
               recycleJedis(jedis);
           }
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```

   }

The shiro's session just a object, so if you want to share session, you need to store it in a share place.